# Is there a way we can reduce the performance time to copy data from one excel file to a different column in another excel file?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have been developing a tool in which data is copied from the input excel file to another excel file at different column location. Currently, I am using sheets.Range function to copy the data from individual column to another by using a loop for the numbers of rows present(Since there is also some data manipulation). Since the input file is too large, it is taking too much time. How can I optimize it?
Note: I cannot skip the loops
Also, I tried parallel programming concept but since the output data entry is dependent on previous row, it cannot be done.
Some colleague suggested me to convert excel into csv file and then manipulate the data. But, I am not sure if this would help. If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: csv can have other issues, how big is big, how slow is slow what issues does profiling outlie

Comment: Where's the problematic code?

Comment: What library are you using to consume Excel files? Is it using default COM lbs or some other, like EPPlus?

Comment: one solution could be copy the entire input sheet into output excel file and perform the loop there? This would mean your code doesn't have to fetch data from another file. Another possible solution could be copy the sheet over, have a vlookup formula to find the correct input value? Again, only offering high level solutions as you haven't posted code, input and output data. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1) Read from input excel file 2) Copy contents as CSV 3) Paste into text tile 4) Read from text file 5) Do data manipulation 6) Write data to output Excel file

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to convert the excel file to csv file like your buddy mentioned. Pulling in a csv object is way less expensive than an excel object. You could do this just by using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and by calling:

```
myExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(@"c:\myExcelWorkbookIsNowA_CSVFile.csv",......)
```

Then work with csv file for data manipulation. And see if performance improves.

Comment: Yes. It helped me to reduce a considerable amount of performance time. Thanks.